# How to read email from Firebase Facebook authentication in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As per the Docs, I have integrated Firebase authentication in Android an have enabled Facebook Login.

The JSON data returned after login is as below, (which includes the email as well)
[image]
Below is the code for reading data in app,

```
public void onFbLogin(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
    String e1=firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getEmail();
    String e2=firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(1).getEmail();
    String e3=firebaseUser.getEmail();
    String displayName = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
    String uID = firebaseUser.getUid();
}
```

Here I am able to get display name and UID. but for all three e1, e2, e3 I get a null value. So I am confused as to how to get the email from data.

Any other Specific way to read the email?

Comment: Add permission for getting the email :
    mFacebookSignInButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

Comment: @Vinay Jaju , Yes i have already added this permission.